# Lubridatate month() for multiple years

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I'd like to make a plot for 2019 and 2020, but I'm running into a problem with the `month()` function from lubridate.
If I run this:

```
df  %>%
  mutate (Month = month(Date, label=T)) %>%
  group_by(Month, Var1) %>%
  summarize (sum = sum(numeric_variable)) %>%
ggplot(aes(Month, sum)) +
  geom_col() +
 facet_wrap(. ~ Var1, scales ="free_y")
```

The data for January 2019 and 2020 and other months are combined in the plot, which makes sense since they're both labelled as `'Jan'` in the Month variable for both 2019 and 2020.

How can I best separate the months for 2019 and 2020 while still keeping the label ('janb, 'feb') and the order of my Month variable? Do I have to reorder them as a factor manually or is there a better way?

Comment: Try `scale_x_date` with `date_labels = "%b"` and `breaks = date_breaks("months")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lubridate is nice for some things, but I much prefer `zoo::as.yearmon` for months and years. There is even a nice `scale_x_yearmon` function for `ggplot`:

```
library(zoo)
df %>%
  mutate (Month = zoo::as.yearmon(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Month, Var1) %>%
  summarize (sum = sum(numeric_variable)) %>%
ggplot(aes(Month, sum)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ Var1, scales ="free_y") + 
  zoo::scale_x_yearmon(format = "%b")
```

[image]

Sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Date = rep(seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = "day"),2),
                                Var1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2],each = 731),
                                numeric_variable = round(runif(2*731,1,100)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ian you set me on the right path. The scale_x_yearmon didn't work for me though. But the since order was right, so I could just convert the outcome of zoo's yearmon a factor and work from there.

```
df %>% 
mutate (Month = as.factor(zoo::as.yearmon(Date))) %>% 
group_by(Month, Var1) %>% 
ggplot(aes(Month, numeric_variable)) +
  geom_col() +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

I know have a 'jan 2019'/ 'dec 2019' and 'jan 2020' / 'dec 2020' at the x-axis which is good enough for now. Issue solved.